# Pthread_create() incorrect start routine parameter passing

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem with pthreads in my C++ application.

In my main function I have:

```
int main(){
    ...

    for(i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++){
        arg[0]=i;
        pthread_create(&tidVec[i], NULL, &thread_body, (void*) arg);
        cout << "tidVec[" << i <<"]: " << tidVec[i] << " arg[0]: " << arg[0] << endl;
    }

    ...
}
```

And in my thread_body function:

```
void * thread_body(void* arg){
    ...
    int* a = (int*)arg;
    cout << "tid: " << pthread_self() << " no.thread: " << a[0] << endl;

    ...
}
```

The output to this (e.g. with numberOfThreads=2) appears to be:

> tidVec[0]: 2932403008 arg[0]: 0
>
> tidVec[1]: 2924010304 arg[0]: 1
>
> tid: 2924010304 no.thread: 1
>
> tid: 2932403008 no.thread: 1

In a more general case, with numberOfThreads=n, no.thread is equal to n-1, for all threads.
Could you please help me figure out why? Is there something I don't understand in how you use the start routine?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please consider using C++11 and [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of pthreads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [*data race*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in your code since you pass the address of the same location (`arg[0]`) to all threads here:

```
    arg[0]=i;
    pthread_create(&tidVec[i], NULL, &thread_body, (void*) arg);
```

You probably meant to use:

```
   arg[i]=i;
```

instead. And the same applies to prints you do in the loop.

Comment: arg is an int* of length 2 which i use to store infomation needed in the thread. And what I want to have is arg[0] to contain the "number" of the thread, while arg[1] is a fixed value for all the threads, e.g. 10. So at each iteration, i modify just the first element of arg, and then i pass the array to pthread_create(). Is that wrong?

Comment: @user2440822 Yes, it's wrong since that leads to a data race. You don't know in what order threads scheduled. So, you might , for example, set arg[0] to 1 but *before* thread1 can read it, main function could change it to 2.

Comment: oh ok now I get where the error is, i'll try to use a global variable for the value which is common to all the threads, and just to pass i as argument to the start routine. My mistake was that I tought that the routine started right away after the pthread_create and before modifying arg[0]. Thank you a lot!